# How can I join two data frames (x and y) and add a row if there is no match in x

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames.  I need to join them based on matching numbers while also adding in a row if a match is not found.  I thought this would work using right_join from dplyr but there are no rows to provide a place holder when a match is not found.

For example:

```
x
sample  coord   value1  value2
c   1059    42  400
c   3267    8   52
c   3298    198 4001
c   3827    0   52
c   3828    1   38
c   3828    1   38
s   1059    78  78
s   3267    41  596
s   3827    646 646
s   3828    17  25

y
ORF Start   Stop    Locus   AltAllele
Orf1a   1059    1059    T265I   T
Orf1a   3267    3267    T1001I  T
Orf1a   3298    3298    Q1011H  CorT
Orf1a   3827    3827    S1188L  C
Orf1a   3828    3828    S1188L  T
```

I want to join these two tables and get this outcome where there is a 'placer' row for the missing match in x.

```
right_join(x, y, by = c("coord" = "Start"))

sample  coord   value1  value2  Orf Stop    Locus   AltAllele
c   1059    42  400 Orf1a   1059    T265I   T
c   3267    8   52  Orf1a   3267    T1001I  T
c   3298    198 4001    Orf1a   3298    Q1011H  CorT
c   3827    0   52  Orf1a   3827    S1188L  C
c   3828    1   38  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
c   3828    1   38  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
s   1059    78  78  Orf1a   1059    T265I   T
s   3267    41  596 Orf1a   3267    T1001I  T
s   3298            Orf1a   3298    Q1011H  CorT
s   3827    646 646 Orf1a   3827    S1188L  C
s   3828    17  25  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
```

But `right_join` is giving me this, where the missing `s` row is not present:

```
sample  coord   value1  value2  Orf Stop    Locus   AltAllele
c   1059    42  400 Orf1a   1059    T265I   T
c   3267    8   52  Orf1a   3267    T1001I  T
c   3298    198 4001    Orf1a   3298    Q1011H  CorT
c   3827    0   52  Orf1a   3827    S1188L  C
c   3828    1   38  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
c   3828    1   38  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
s   1059    78  78  Orf1a   1059    T265I   T
s   3267    41  596 Orf1a   3267    T1001I  T
s   3827    646 646 Orf1a   3827    S1188L  C
s   3828    17  25  Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T
```

I have also experimented with left_join and full_join which don't produce the expected outcome.  How can I retain a row for non-matches?

Here are example data:

```
x = structure(list(sample = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "s", 
"s", "s", "s"), coord = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 
3828L, 1059L, 3267L, 3827L, 3828L), value1 = c(42L, 8L, 198L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 78L, 41L, 646L, 17L), value2 = c(400L, 52L, 4001L, 
52L, 38L, 38L, 78L, 596L, 646L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

y = structure(list(ORF = c("Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a"
), Start = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L), Stop = c(1059L, 
3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L), Locus = c("T265I", "T1001I", "Q1011H", 
"S1188L", "S1188L"), AltAllele = c("T", "T", "CorT", "C", "T"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: All of your `x$coord` values are contained in `y$Start`, so naturally, you won't get any blank rows.  Everything here **has** a match!  However, with different data in `x$coord`, including some values not present in `y$Start`, your `right_join()` should be just fine.

Comment: I feel like this behavior might actually make sense, because the join functions  don't "know" that you have two different groups via `sample` since that is not part of the join. Someone may come by with a better solution, but what do you think about adding all combinations of `coord` for each `sample` after (or before, I guess) with `tidyr::complete()`? Like `right_join(x, y, by = c("coord" = "Start")) %>% complete(sample, coord)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that since every coord has a Start match that there won't be any rows with missing values.  I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: @aosmith solution works.  It fills in the remainder of the row with NA which drops the information from the y data frame.  It is a viable solution if you don't need to retain the information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something similar to:

```
library(purrr)

split(x, ~ sample) %>%
  imap_dfr(~ .x %>%
              right_join(y, by = c("coord" = "Start")) %>%
              mutate(sample = .y))
```

Returning:

```
   sample coord value1 value2   ORF Stop  Locus AltAllele
1       c  1059     42    400 Orf1a 1059  T265I         T
2       c  3267      8     52 Orf1a 3267 T1001I         T
3       c  3298    198   4001 Orf1a 3298 Q1011H      CorT
4       c  3827      0     52 Orf1a 3827 S1188L         C
5       c  3828      1     38 Orf1a 3828 S1188L         T
6       c  3828      1     38 Orf1a 3828 S1188L         T
7       s  1059     78     78 Orf1a 1059  T265I         T
8       s  3267     41    596 Orf1a 3267 T1001I         T
9       s  3827    646    646 Orf1a 3827 S1188L         C
10      s  3828     17     25 Orf1a 3828 S1188L         T
11      s  3298     NA     NA Orf1a 3298 Q1011H      CorT
```

Data used:

```
x = structure(list(sample = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "s", "s", "s", "s"), coord = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 3828L, 1059L, 3267L, 3827L, 3828L), value1 = c(42L, 8L, 198L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 78L, 41L, 646L, 17L), value2 = c(400L, 52L, 4001L, 52L, 38L, 38L, 78L, 596L, 646L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)) 
y = structure(list(ORF = c("Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a"), Start = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L), Stop = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L), Locus = c("T265I", "T1001I", "Q1011H", "S1188L", "S1188L"), AltAllele = c("T", "T", "CorT", "C", "T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Just FYI, in the data provided by OP, everything actually **does** have a match, so it's no surprise that there were no "placeholder rows"!

Comment: ktiu  Your solution is giving me an error:  Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: @Greg Yes, my solution includes some guesswork as to what is the desired behavior :)

Comment: @aminards Please check that your variable types match what you provided in the example data.

Comment: @ktiu My actual data does have extra columns.  However the columns in y and the columns sample, and coord in x all are the same type.  Both are data frames as well.    Why would having extra columns in x that are not used for any of the matches cause a problem?

Comment: @aminards If you provide data that lets me reproduce the issue I will take a look.

Comment: @ktiu  I figured it out.  I had a typo in the command .  Your solution works fine.